# How to securely lock 100% a microcontroller like ESP32 or ATtiny85 or any other ATtiny?

Tags: microcontroller, attiny, esp32, fuse-bits

I have been doing research on how to securely lock and prevent 100% from someone seeing my code.

ESP32 can be "hacked" see [here](https://limitedresults.com/2019/11/pwn-the-esp32-forever-flash-encryption-and-sec-boot-keys-extraction/).

ATtiny has fuse bits that can be set to protect the code but again someone who knows how to or pay someone can get them unlocked.

This is not a question about if I really want it to be locked or not and if my code is so important and if I am Chuck Norris in programming.

Is there any microcontroller ESP32, ATtin85, other ATtiny family, or any other microcontroller which would provide 100% or nearly 100% protection?

Comment: Against what threat? Someone with a JTAG adapter? Someone with an acid bath and de-capping equipment?

Comment: against anyone who wants to see my code with any different way.

Comment: Usually the programm memory can be protected from reading. But memory can be erased or reprogrammed.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if someone erases it or reprograms it. But even fuse bits etc can be "hacked" on esp32 and attiny.. so there is no point to set them anyway..

Comment: No, there is probably no reasonable way that you can protect against **anyone** who wants to "see" your code in **any different way**. You need think about the actual adversary that you expect, what capabilities they have, and how much time & money they will spend. Then you design your security to make it impractical for that adversary to hack your system.

Comment: Nonsuch thing as 100%. Man made it, man can hack it. The esp32-s2( need to confirm) has more robust encryption hardware that makes it harder to hack. Note that most systems are compromised not by the strength of the encryption. If you want super strong protection, there are specialist crypto processors - the DS5000 was an older example of such a device. Be prepared to pay though.

Comment: The level of security system defined by the time and equipment price to hack it. Nothing gives 100% protection. It is all about it the efforts worse the result.

Comment: If you want an absolutely unbreakable defense, how do you intend to defend yourself from a supply chain attack where your production facility receives backdoored microcontrollers that allow a readout to be done by the attacker? Or if someone coerces/bribes one of your engineers to give up details of your system? Consider revising your question to **explicitly** indicate the threat model you want to defend against.

Comment: Just checking, but you are aware that the source code will not be in the MCU, just the compiled code?

Comment: @Transistor yes I am aware.. but then why they give the option of secure boot and flash encryption if anyway the compiled code doesn't help them ? Isn't the compiled code vulnerable to reverse engineering?

Comment: All microcontrollers can be hacked at some cost. The common ones, quite cheaply and easily by firms that specialize in it. There are legitimate reasons to do so, btw.

Comment: If someone getting access to your device's code would compromise its security, then you didn't design it right. Given that, why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: @kartman I had to look up the DS3000. Unfortunately the third hit was for a paper saying "For the DS5000 security processor, a short voltage drop sometimes released the security lock without erasing secret data". So supporting the original point - its so hard to secure something in the wild.

Comment: If you tell us exactly what level of attacker you need to defend against (A nation state with a billion dollar budget? A national corporation with a million dollar budget? A hobbyist with a soldering iron and an acid bath?) we can tell you what technologies are appropriate. Note that they get expensive *fast* if your adversary is sophisticated and well-resourced. For example, you can run any code you want in an nShield HSM and it can withstand an adversary with a multi-million dollar budget and it protects both code and data, but they cost around $30,000 each.

Comment: @tomnexus. The DS5000 is very old. It was fairly popular in its day. Nowadays, devices to listen and inject pulses to disrupt the security are cheap and commonplace now. Many modern devices fall prey to these attacks. Bleeding edge devices are more immune to that type of attack.

Comment: what sophisticated code can you have for atiny, which is not simple to reverse engineer as black box?

Answer (score 5):

There is a constant arms race between manufacturers and interested parties that has been going on for decades. As a result modern uC's are quite hard to extract code from. I don't think decapping is feasible anymore, atleast not with any benchtop equipment. With a lockbit set on a modern uC multimillion operations are required to extract code.

And for most of us, that is never ever something we will go up against. (and "we" will loose every single time. If an interested party is *that* interested they *will* find a way.)

If you are concerned I would just get a modern or recently revised uC, set the lock bit and unless you are building state-secret code or code in a multi-billion product it will not get extracted.

Answer (score 3):

No microcontroller or semiconductor is 100% unhackable. Modern manufacturing can make them difficult to hack, but with enough money and time they will be reversed engineered. For some the money and time needed will be much higher than others.

There are security minded microcontrollers that you can purchase. Google "security microcontroller" for loads of details.

Answer (score 1):

Bear in mind that the weakest link may actually end up being your development environment -- for example, if you're using bog standard Windows on off the shelf consumer Intel/AMD products, and the PC with the codebase is connected to the Internet with random proprietary software installed on it, it may be significantly easier (and more valuable) for a motivated attacker to hack that PC via readily available exploits than to try to extract the binary from the microprocessor.  To a certain degree it gets even worse if you're using cloud-based services to store or process the codebase.

Even if you're doing development offline on a less vulnerable operating system, a microprocessor is generally simple enough in terms of functionality that it can be clean room reverse engineered and replaced with a functional equivalent.

At the end of the day the level and type of protections you require do come down to the specific actions you are trying to prevent -- i.e. are you trying to prevent direct cloning?  Stop leakage of some kind of protected IP (DRM)?  Protect revenue derived from a novel process or algorithm?  All of those goals have different methods to best accomplish them, from lock bits to patents, and no one solution will cover all in the most effective way possible.